# Add 2 months to current timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, date, date-arithmetic

How can I add months to a timestamp value in Oracle? In my query, it's getting converted to date value instead:

```
     SELECT add_months(current_timestamp,2) 
     FROM   dual;
```

The actual output is:

```
     ADD_MONTH
     11-MAR-13
```

The expected output is:

```
    2013-01-01 00:00:00.000000000+00:00
```

Comment: Next time you run across this sort of problem, the term you want to Google for is "date math".

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the date **and the time** as a `TIMESTAMP` data type:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 2), 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI'), 
'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI') from dual;
```

If you need more or less precision (E.G. rounding) than what is above, adjust the date formats (both need to be the same format).  For example, this will return 2 months down to the seconds level of precision:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSTIMESTAMP, 2), 
'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```

This is the closest I can get (as a character) to the format you need:

```
select TO_CHAR( 
TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSTIMESTAMP, 2), 
'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR') from dual;
```

Comment: the first statement you have is dodgy, as its relying on implicit conversion, and depending on the NLS settings, may actually fail (or give a incorrect date).

Comment: Yes, since TO_TIMESTAMP only takes characters, and not dates, I am removing the 1ST and leaving only the conversions with explicit date formats..

Comment: Thanks that worked for adding 2 months, but I need the output in this format.

Comment: 2013-01-11 00:00:00.000000000+00:00

Comment: This is the closest I can get to that - it is returned as a character though:

Comment: select TO_CHAR( 
TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSTIMESTAMP, 2), 
'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR') from dual;

Comment: Using `ADD_MONTHS` converts the `TIMESTAMP` to a `DATE` and will truncate the fractional seconds to `0` when you cast it back to a `TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will about give you what you're looking for:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,2))
            + (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)),
       'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SSxFFTZR') FROM DUAL;
```

The problem with using the interval methods is that you can get an unexpected error depending on the date you run the query.  E.g.

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('31-JAN-2012') + NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'MONTH') FROM DUAL;
```

That query returns:

```
ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
```

This is because it attempts to return February 31, which is not a valid date.

ADD_MONTHS is a "safer" way to date math, in that where the interval query would throw an error, ADD_MONTHS will return the last date of the month (Feb 28 or 29 depending on the year) in the above example.

Comment: There are several problems with this answer - first `ADD_MONTHS` will implicitly convert the `TIMESTAMP` to a `DATE` dropping the fractional seconds but it **keeps** the rest of the time component then you add the interval between the current time and the time truncated to the start of the day so you are adding the time component of the timestamp twice (but the fractional seconds only once).

Comment: Second, `TO_TIMESTAMP( timestampstring, format_model )` uses the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session parameter as the default format model but the implicit conversion of a `DATE` to a string (since the first argument of `TO_TIMESTAMP` is a string) uses the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter - relying on implicit conversion means these settings must be identical and it is not usual for `TIMESTAMP`s and `DATE`s to have the same format so this will not be the case for the majority of users.

Comment: You want: `SELECT CAST( ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ), 2 ) AS TIMESTAMP ) + ( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - TRUNC( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) AS two_months_from_now FROM DUAL;`

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle:

```
SELECT
  TIMESTAMP'2014-01-30 08:16:32',                                  -- TS we want to increase by 1 month
--TIMESTAMP'2014-01-30 08:16:32' + NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH'),    -- raises ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
--TIMESTAMP'2014-01-30 08:16:32' + INTERVAL '1' MONTH,             -- raises ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
  ADD_MONTHS(TIMESTAMP'2014-01-30 08:16:32', 1),                   -- works but is a date :(
  CAST(ADD_MONTHS(TIMESTAMP'2014-01-30 08:16:32', 1) AS TIMESTAMP) -- works
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Using `ADD_MONTHS` converts the `TIMESTAMP` to a `DATE` and will truncate the fractional seconds to `0` when you cast it back to a `TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT current_timestamp + INTERVAL '2' MONTH from dual;
```

To display this in your desired format, use `TO_CHAR`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(current_timestamp + INTERVAL '2' MONTH, 
       'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9TZH:TZM') from dual;
2013-03-11 23:58:14.789501000+01:00
```

Comment: You should be aware that this method can throw an ORA-01839 error depending on the date it is called.  

For example, running: "SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('30-JAN-2012','DD-MON-YYYY') + numtoyminterval(1,'month') from dual;"  throws an error because it would return February 30, which does not exist.

Comment: Sorry -- I should have been more specific -- the error will be thrown when using intervals in general.  So:
"SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('30-JAN-2012','DD-MON-YYYY') + interval '1' month from dual;" would cause the same error.

Comment: I tested it before editing, but with INTERVAL '2' MONTH, which doesn't  throw an error, of course, as it's then in March. Silly me!  Still many thanks for your help!

Comment: `SELECT TIMESTAMP '2067-12-30 01:23:45.6789' + INTERVAL '2' MONTH FROM DUAL` raises the exception `ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified` as there is no 30th February

Answer (score -1):

For Oracle:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP(Sysdate,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24-MI-SS') + 60
from dual;

select sysdate + interval '2' month from dual;

select TO_TIMESTAMP (Sysdate + interval '2' month,  'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24-MI-SS')
from dual
;
```

Result1:

```
| TO_TIMESTAMP(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYYHH24-MI-SS')+60 |
----------------------------------------------------
|                     March, 12 0013 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Result2:

```
|     SYSDATE+INTERVAL'2'MONTH |
--------------------------------
| March, 11 2013 21:41:10+0000 |
```

Result3:

```
| TO_TIMESTAMP(SYSDATE+INTERVAL'2'MONTH,'DD-MON-YYYYHH24-MI-SS') |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                   March, 11 0013 00:00:00+0000 |
```

- [sqlffidle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f152e/5).

Comment: @user1968156 please take a look at this as well and comment :)

Comment: I saw that, but I want year in the front like this.

Comment: 2013-01-11 00:00:00.000000000+00:00

Comment: @user1968156 sorry, but very simple :D just change the format :D to `YYYYMMDD HH24-MI-SS'

Comment: I tried that but it gives the output like this :              select TO_TIMESTAMP(SYSDATE+INTERVAL'2'MONTH,'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual;                                            13-MAR-11 12.00.00 AM

Comment: `SELECT TIMESTAMP '2067-12-30 01:23:45.6789' + INTERVAL '2' MONTH FROM DUAL` raises the exception `ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified` as there is no 30th February