# SQL - Selecting records within a certain period with unix timestamps?

Tags: sql, timestamp

I am trying to extract records from a table that are 1 month old relative to `NOW`. This seemed easy enough with tables having sql dates eg: `WHERE DocDate>=CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH`

But the dates in this table are expressed as unix timestamps which does not seem as straightforward. So far I've tested the following:

```
SELECT articleviewed, COUNT(articleviewed) AS Viewed, articleviewedtitle, timestampx
FROM swdata.uos_swkb_stats_views
WHERE timestampx <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND timestampx >= 1389004991
GROUP BY articleviewed
ORDER BY Viewed DESC
```

which is ok, but I need `timestampx >= 1389004991` to be relative to `NOW`.

the following yeild incorrect results or incorrect syntax

```
WHERE timestampx <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND timestampx >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1 MONTH
WHERE timestampx <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

---

A colleague has provided the following solution which seems to work ok, apparently I need to convert/define the timestamp as follows.

WHERE timestampx >=(unix_timestamp(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))

Comment: And your database engine is,...,?

Comment: mySQL, sorry I'm a nubie to Stack and programing.

Answer (score 0):

which platform?

Oracle

```
 CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1*30
```

or get an eye there

[Add 2 months to current timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286877/add-2-months-to-current-timestamp)

```
 SELECT current_timestamp - INTERVAL '1' MONTH from dual;
```